# C Program to find UP and DOWN machines.?

Tags: c++, networking, ip

Suppose I have a scenario like below :

There are about 225 Computers having the following range of IP addresses and hostnames:-

```
PC-LAB         IP ADDRESS RANGE       HOSTNAME RANGE
PC-LAB1  10.11.2.01 -   10.11.2.30  ccl1pc01 - ccl1pc30
PC-LAB2  10.11.3.01 -   10.11.3.30  ccl2pc01 - ccl2pc30
PC-LAB3  10.11.4.01 -   10.11.4.45  ccl3pc01 - ccl3pc45
PC-LAB4  10.11.5.01 -   10.11.5.50  ccl4pc01 - ccl4pc50
PC-LAB5  10.13.6.01 -   10.13.6.65  ccl5pc01 – ccl5pc65
```

I want to write a program (**in C / C++**) that will take the above IP address and hostname ranges as input and create two separate files, one with 225 entries of IP 
addresses and another with 225 entries of hostnames..

Then the program will figure out which of these machines are **up** and which are **down** and then create two files one containing 
***hostname***  and ***IP addresses*** of the systems which are ***UP*** and another which are ***DOWN***.

E.g.

```
FILE1.down
Hostname   IP address
ccl1pc10   10.8.2.10
ccl5pc25   10.11.5.25
```

**Note** : If any ubuntu command simplifies this work..we can use that in the program for sure..!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at **fping**

Run this command, sit back and relax:

```
fping ccl{1..6}pc{01..60}
```

this will print a list of

- All hosts that have a DNS name/IP record and are up
- All hosts that have a DNS name/IP record but are down
- All hosts that are not in the DNS (I guess you can ignore these)

Regards

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Nmap](http://nmap.org/). You might need to create a small wrapper to handle the input and output in the format you want, but it should do exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Is this homework, ie do you have to do it programmatically in C?

Otherwise there a dozen of *already existing* monitoring frameworks, with several already in Ubuntu: munin, nagios, zabbix, ...

Comment: Sad..but i have to do it in C..!!..i told we can use any existing ubuntu command that simplies all this work..!!

Comment: kinda..if u can help..it would be awesome..!!